# How to speed up window leveling (brightness, contrast)?

Tags: javascript, optimization, algorithm, performance, image

I have to apply window leveling on Canvas Medical Image (CR).  I have to get a pixel array from C# `Component.lutArr`, which is a lookup table array coming as a C# component and which I use in JavaScript. On click of the button, I have to call the function `ApplyWLCust()`.  In this function, all process done getting result perfect. For window leveling, use bit shifting, which takes around 585ms. I have to reduce this time.  What should I do?

```
var imagewc = document.getElementById("text1").value;
                var imageww = document.getElementById("text2").value;     
pixelArr = [11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11..]  
        if (pixelArr != null)
                {
                    for (var i = 0, n = pixelArr.length; i < n; i++)
                    {
                        pix = pixelArr[i];
                        pix = ApplyWL(pix, imagewc, imageww);
                        pix = lutArr[pix];



                    // var red = (pix & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
                    v = i * 4;
                    imagedata[v] = pix & 0xff;
                    imagedata[v + 1] = (pix >>> 8) & 0xff;
                    imagedata[v + 2] = (pix >>> 16) & 0xff;
                    imagedata[v + 3] = 255;
                }
                //  offscreenCtx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
                offscreenCtx.putImageData(g, 0, 0);
            }
function ApplyWL(value, _valwindowCenter, _valwindowWidth)
        {
            Recalculate(_valwindowCenter, _valwindowWidth);
            if (value <= _windowStart)
                value = _minimumOutputValue;
            else if (value > _windowEnd)
                value = _maximumOutputValue;
            else
            {
                value = Math.round((((value - _windowCenterMin05) / _windowWidthMin1) + 0.5) * 255.0);
            }
            return value;
        }

        var _minimumOutputValue = 0;
        var _maximumOutputValue = 255;
        function Recalculate(_valwindowCenter, _valwindowWidth)
        {
            if (!_valid)
            {
                _windowCenterMin05 = _valwindowCenter - 0.5;
                _windowWidthMin1 = _valwindowWidth - 1;
                _windowWidthDiv2 = _windowWidthMin1 / 2;
                _windowStart = (_windowCenterMin05 - _windowWidthDiv2);
                _windowEnd = (_windowCenterMin05 + _windowWidthDiv2);
                _valid = true;
            }
        }


Width<input id="text1" type="text" />
    center<input id="text2" type="text" />
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Apply" onclick="ApplyWLCust();" />
    </br> time required<input id="text3" type="text" />
    <canvas style="height: 500px; width: 500px; display1: none; background-color: black;
                border: 1px solid red;" id="offscreenCanvas">
```

Answer (score 2):

I think we need more code,

- Where are `imagewc`, `imageww`, and `lutArr` defined ? Those are all 3 unfortunate variable names by the way

Regardless, I think a large speed up should be gained from calling `Recalculate` once before the loop on `pixelArr` since `imagewc` and `imageww` never change in that loop.

Furthermore, since value is cut of between `0` and `255`, you should pre-calculate the array of values.

```
var lookup= [] , i;
for( var i = _minimumOutputValue  ; i < _maximumOutputValue+1; i++ )
    lookup[i] = Math.round((((i- _windowCenterMin05) / _windowWidthMin1) + 0.5) * 255.0);
```

then your function would be:

```
function ApplyWL(value, _valwindowCenter, _valwindowWidth)
{
   if (value <= _windowStart)
     return lookup[_minimumOutputValue  ];
   if (value > _windowEnd)
      return lookup[_maximumOutputValue];
   return lookup[value]
}
```

I might be wrong about the ranges of lookup, your table might have to be larger, but I am sure you realize the value of a lookup table at this point.

EDIT:

I wrote some code to look at it, some notes:
* I moved the variables to the top, please make sure that all variables are declared with `var`
* Only constructors should start with an uppercase letter

```
var imagewc = document.getElementById("text1").value,
    imageww = document.getElementById("text2").value,
    _minimumOutputValue = 0,
    _maximumOutputValue = 255,    
    _valid,
    cacheWL = [],
    pixelArr = [11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11]; 

if (pixelArr != null)
{
  //Move this out of the for loop
  recalculate(_valwindowCenter, _valwindowWidth);
  //Then set the cache which needs the results of `recalculate`
  cacheWL();
  for (var i = 0, n = pixelArr.length,v = 0,i < n; i++)
  {
    pix = pixelArr[i];
    pix = ApplyWL(pix, imagewc, imageww);
    pix = lutArr[pix];

    imagedata[v] = pix & 0xff;
    imagedata[v + 1] = (pix >>> 8) & 0xff;
    imagedata[v + 2] = (pix >>> 16) & 0xff;
    imagedata[v + 3] = 255;
    //Instead of doing a multiplication, you can keep adding 4
    v += 4; 
  }
  offscreenCtx.putImageData(g, 0, 0);
}

function setCacheWL()
{
  for( var i = _minimumOutputValue ; i <= _maximumOutputValue ; i++ )
    cacheWL[i] = Math.round((((i - _windowCenterMin05) / _windowWidthMin1) + 0.5) * 255.0);
}


function ApplyWL(value, _valwindowCenter, _valwindowWidth)
{
   if (value <= _windowStart)
     return cacheWL[_minimumOutputValue];
   if (value > _windowEnd)
      return cacheWL[_maximumOutputValue];
   return cacheWL[value]
}

function recalculate(_valwindowCenter, _valwindowWidth)
{
  if (!_valid)
  {
    _windowCenterMin05 = _valwindowCenter - 0.5;
    _windowWidthMin1 = _valwindowWidth - 1;
    _windowWidthDiv2 = _windowWidthMin1 / 2;
    _windowStart = (_windowCenterMin05 - _windowWidthDiv2);
    _windowEnd = (_windowCenterMin05 + _windowWidthDiv2);
    _valid = true;
  }
}
```